# Не получается связать модели по ForeignKey

Tags: python-3.x, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему!
Есть следующие модели данных:

```
class Dealers(models.Model):

    # данная модель хранит информацию о дилерах
    dealer_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    web_site = models.URLField()

class Stocks(models.Model):

    # данная модель хранит остатки на складах дилеров
    row_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealers, on_delete='cascade', db_column='dealer')
    product = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    discount_group = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    update_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dealer', 'warehouse', '-update_date']
```

Сначала я через shell в Django вношу данные в таблицу Dealers, таким образом:

```
Dealers.objects.create(dealer_name=’Some_dealer’, web_site=’Some_URL’)
```

Затем отдельным файлом загружаю данные из csv в таблицу Stocks, таким образом:

```
create_objects = Stocks(
                            dealer=dealer,
                            product=product,
                            product_id=product_id,
                            discount_group=discount_group,
                            warehouse=warehouse,
                            quantity=quantity,
                            update_date=update_date
                        )
                        create_objects.save()
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "Some_dealer": "Stocks.dealer" must be a "Dealers" instance.
```

При этом, если загружать данные в Stocks без ForeignKey, то все отлично грузится, а как только пытаюсь создать связь между Dealers и Stocks получаю такую ошибку. Some dealer есть и в Dealers и в Stocks 100%.
Подскажите, в чем я не прав?

Миграция выглядит так:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Dealers',
            fields=[
                ('dealer_id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('dealer_name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('web_site', models.URLField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User_Request',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('request_datetime', models.DateField(auto_now=True)),
                ('request_text', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete='cascade', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Stocks',
            fields=[
                ('row_id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('product', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('product_id', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
                ('discount_group', models.CharField(max_length=4)),
                ('warehouse', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('quantity', models.IntegerField()),
                ('update_date', models.DateField()),
                ('dealer', models.ForeignKey(on_delete='cascade', to='view_stocks.Dealers')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['dealer', 'warehouse', '-update_date'],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Покажите, что за `dealer` у вас при создании объекта? Как его получаете?

Comment: Если я правильно вопрос понял, то вот так:
#Запускаю shell
python manage.py shell
#Импортирую модель Dealers в shell
from view_stocks.models import Dealers
#Создаю объект в БД
Dealers.objects.create(dealer_name='Some_dealer', web_site='https://some_dealer.ru/contact')
Все, после этого объект dealer появляется в БД.

Comment: `dealer = Dealers.objects.create(dealer_name='Some_dealer', web_site='some_dealer.ru/contact')`

Comment: И потом создавайте `Stocks`

Comment: Все равно та же ошибка(

Comment: `Stocks.objects.create(dealer=Dealers.objects.filter(name="<dealer name>").first(), ...)` не ?

Comment: Вам бы скинуть побольше кода, ибо если у вас все еще ошибка, то в что то делаете не так